# Excel command line switches - positions

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, command-line-arguments

I notice that when I enter :

excel /r "c:\temp1\test001.xls"

I get read only. When I enter

excel "c:\temp1\test001.xls" /r

I do not get readonly.

When I enter

excel /s "c:\temp1\test001.xls"

I get safemode.

When I enter

excel "c:\temp1\test001.xls" /s

I still get safemode.

Is there any kind of logic to when switches go before or after?
Or is it a bit all over the place?

Thanks

Comment: Safe mode is application-scope setting. `/s` key means "... and run in safe mode ...". Read-only is workbook-scope setting. `/r` key means "... and open next files in read-only mode ...". If running `excel 1.xls 2.xls /r 3.xls 4.xls` 1 and 2 are opened in RW, whereas 3 and 4 in RO mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As so kindly explained in Comments by [Akina](https://superuser.com/users/910710/akina), the scope of the [command-line switches of Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291288/description-of-the-startup-switches-for-excel) can be either session-wide (affecting many things about how Excel works), or workbook-specific (just the specified files are affected).

When you choose Safe mode with **/s**, that setting alters the way that session of Excel works, for all workbooks, until you close Excel.

> It ignores all files in the Application Data\Microsoft\Xlstart folder,
>   the default XLStart folder located in the directory where Excel or
>   Office is installed, and the alternate startup file location specified
>   on the General tab of the Excel Options dialog box. It also forces
>   Excel to ignore  the toolbar file (Excel.xlb or .xlb). You
>   will see "Safe Mode" in the Excel title bar when you launch it with
>   the /s switch.

When you select Read-only, that applies only to the Excel files which **follow** the **/r** switch on that command line (the "workbook-scope" setting).

`excel 1.xls 2.xls /r 3.xls 4.xls`
opens 1.xls and 2.xls normally,
while 3.xls and 4.xls open read-only.